# Flutter webview error bitcode bundle could not be generated

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, webview, bitcode

I'm making a flutter application connected to an e-commerce website. I have already published it for android. When building it for testing on Xcode everything worked fine but when I tried to archive it I get the following error:

*ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
'/Users/serenacaccavari/Documents/app/1.9.1/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter'
was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build
file '/Users/serenacaccavari/Documents/app/1.9.1/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

Things I tried:

- Disabling bitcode for pods config
- Cleaning and rebuilding for ios in flutter

thanks in advance to everyone answering

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling bitcode by adding this to the `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```